# Include with url variable in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a "create new object" button in a template file. I want to include the button in several places at my website, but I want to include the template with a link. I've tried:

```
{% include "snippets/icon_add.html" with link="/create_new_item/" only %}
```

But I want to use the benefits of `{% url 'create_new_item' %}`. Can I do something like:

```
{% include "snippets/icon_add.html" with link={% url 'create_new_item' %} only %}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try with `{% url ... as var %}` syntax. Example:

```
{% url 'create_new_item' as the_url %}
{% include "snippets/icon_add.html" with link=the_url %}
```

Docs link [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: With the catch that `{% url 'create_new_item' as the_url %}` does not thrown an error if the url doesn't exist.